# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.

Tags: java

This is My code:

```
      Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.open(filename);
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().getSheet(sheetno);
        Cells cells=worksheet.getCells();
        int num=cells.getMaxDataRow();
        int num1=cells.getMaxDataColumn();
        int OCount=1;
                     for (int n1=startpos+1;n1<endpos;n1++)
         {   if (cells.checkCell(n1, Colno).getValue()==null )
                       {         Cell cell=cells.getCell(n1,Colno);
                                Style style = cells.getCell( n1,Colno).getStyle();
                                style.setColor(Color.TEAL);
                                cell.setStyle(style);
                       } else if(cells.checkCell(n1, Colno).getValue().toString().length()==0) { Cell cell=cells.getCell(n1,Colno);
                                Style style = cells.getCell( n1,Colno).getStyle();
                                style.setColor(Color.TEAL);
                                cell.setStyle(style); } else{ double intCounter = Double.parseDouble(cells.checkCell(n1,Colno).getValue().toString());
                          System.out.println(cells.checkCell(n1,Colno).getValue().toString());
                          if(intCounter!=Count){
                                       Cell cell=cells.getCell(n1,Colno);
                                        Style style = cells.getCell( n1,Colno).getStyle();
                                        style.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                        cell.setStyle(style);
                                  }
                              }
                  Count=Count+1;

             } workbook.save("C:\\output.xls",FileFormatType.EXCEL97TO2003);
```

I am trying to check that Sr no is in sequential order or not. it is working fine if there is no empty string " ". For empty string it throws

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.**

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: post full stacktrace in the future, it helps finding the problem faster

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line of code:

```
Double.parseDouble(cells.checkCell(n1,Colno).getValue().toString());
```

There you try to make a Double out of an empty String. [Check the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) and you will see that the NumberFormatException is the intended behavior. So you either have to check first if the String is empty or implement proper error handling.

Here a quote from the API for the method Double.parseDouble(...):

> Throws: `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable double.

Answer (score 0):

its better to handle these cases by using a utility method.

```
private Double getCorrectedDouble(CellValues... ){
  //check and handle empty fields
  //return new Double(0) if the target is empty 

}
```

Comment: Hi all i am checking this condition two times still getting Error msg

Comment: what data is entered in the cell? NumberFormatException is thrown if the string does not contain a parsable double.

Comment: Checking the condition for ONCE for each cell(before getting Double value from it) is enough. You don't need to check 2 times.

Comment: i think the cell contains white space or ""

Comment: thats why you are getting the exception. you should avoid this by checking the content of cell before doing : Double.parseDouble(cells.checkCell(n1,Colno).getValue().toString());

Comment: How can i find  only space. it throws Number Format Exception                                                                                                                                   'public static boolean isStartingWithWhitespace(String str) {
   
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty())
      return false;
   return str.substring(0,1).trim().isEmpty();
}'

Comment: I recommend you to use Debug tools in your IDE. Run your program in debug mode by setting break points. It helps you to locate the error.